# How to have multiple action buttons for a single form in Grails

Tags: forms, grails, grails-2.0

I have a form and action buttons as follows

```
<g:form  controller="mail"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="mailComposer" name="mailComposer">
    <g:submitButton action="sendMail" name="send"  id="send" value="Send" />
    <g:submitButton action="save"  name="save" id="save" value="Save Now" />    
</g:form>
```

And in MailController, I have defined `save()` and `sendMail()` actions.

When I click on any button, The action is called not properly instead it's going to this URL `"http://localhost:8080/myapp/mail/index/mailComposer"`.

The `submitToRemote` works fine.

**Can we have multiple actions of different controllers in single form.**

*I have done this before in Grails 1.3.x version, But in Grails 2.0.4, it's doing like this.*

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't it be using [actionSubmit](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html)?:

```
<g:form  controller="mail"  enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="mailComposer" name="mailComposer">
    <g:actionSubmit action="sendMail" value="Send" />
    <g:actionSubmit action="save" value="Save Now" />    
</g:form>
```